# Can I write "public int i = 0" in main method?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I just wrote a program for searching an element in an array. It worked fine though. BUT, when I changed the access specifier of variable `int i` to `public`, error comes (it had no explicit access modifier before, so I thought access was default). So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
public class Search {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = new int[5];
        public int i;
        int num, flag = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the array elements");
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number to be found");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (num == arr[i]) {
                System.out.println("Element Found!");
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            System.out.println("Element not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: public class Search
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     int arr[] = new int[5];
  public int i;
  int num, flag = 0;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the array elements");
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter the number to be found");
  num = sc.nextInt();
  
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
   if(num == arr[i])
   {
    System.out.println("Element Found!");
    flag = 1;
    break;
   }
  }
  if(flag == 0)
  System.out.println("Element not found");
 }
}

Comment: No. You can't declare a class field **inside** a method.

Comment: What do you mean Elliott? I'm new into Java. Thanks for understanding an d replyin.

Comment: What do you mean you changed access specifier of variable to int? Int isn't an access specifier, it's a type.

Comment: @TZHX Read the title.

Comment: @asfasasf I mean exactly what I said. You **can't** have `public int i;` *in* `main` (or any other method).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did read the title, then I read the question. Using the right words to describe problems is important in programming.

Comment: Oh, so with any variable or method, I cannot use access specifier in main method? To do that, I must declare/initialize it as a class member, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why access specifiers can't be used for variables declared inside method in a Java Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832001/why-access-specifiers-cant-be-used-for-variables-declared-inside-method-in-a-ja)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Access Modifier`, such as `private` and `public` inside a method.

You can have `int i = 0;`inside a method.

Comment: Oh, so with any variable or method, I cannot use access specifier in main method? To do that, I must declare/initialize it as a class member, right?

Comment: Okay brother. Thanks a lot for helping. :)) You were really helpful. :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. :)